# How can I combine two arrays of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having two arrays as

```
array1 = [
  { 'Full Name': 'ACC  stu',
     Email: 'test@gmail.com',
    Status: 'Cold',
    Tel: '1111111'
   }, {
    'Full Name': 'ADD  stu',
     Email: 'test2@gmail.com',
     Status: 'Cold',
     Tel: '222222'
   }, .. so on
]
array2 = [
  { address: 'XXXX',
     city: 'AAAAA'
   }, {
    address: 'QQQQ',
     city: 'ZZZZ'
   }, .. so on
]
```

The length of both the arrays is the same.
I want to combine them in a way, that the result is

```
result = [
  { 'Full Name': 'ACC  stu',
     Email: 'test@gmail.com',
    Status: 'Cold',
    Tel: '1111111',
    address: 'XXXX',
    city: 'AAAAA'
   }, {
    'Full Name': 'ADD  stu',
     Email: 'test2@gmail.com',
     Status: 'Cold',
     Tel: '222222',
     address: 'QQQQ',
     city: 'ZZZZ'
   }, .. so on
]
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can iterate over `array1` and at each iteration return an object containing the properties of the elements in `array1` and `array2` at the index `i`:

```js
const 
array1 = [
  { 'Full Name': 'ACC  stu',
     Email: 'test@gmail.com',
     Status: 'Cold',
     Tel: '1111111'
  }, 
  {
    'Full Name': 'ADD  stu',
     Email: 'test2@gmail.com',
     Status: 'Cold',
     Tel: '222222'
   }
],
array2 = [
  { address: 'XXXX',
     city: 'AAAAA'
  }, 
  {
    address: 'QQQQ',
     city: 'ZZZZ'
  }
];

const res = array1.map((obj, i) => ({ ...obj, ...(array2[i] || {}) }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice and concise but it would be more useful if you explained the one-liner

Answer (score 1):

You could user either zip utility function or using map as below. Use spread operator to combine.

```js
let array1, array2, result;
array1 = [
  { 'Full Name': 'ACC  stu',
     Email: 'test@gmail.com',
    Status: 'Cold',
    Tel: '1111111'
   }, {
    'Full Name': 'ADD  stu',
     Email: 'test2@gmail.com',
     Status: 'Cold',
     Tel: '222222'
   }
]
array2 = [
  { address: 'XXXX',
     city: 'AAAAA'
   }, {
    address: 'QQQQ',
     city: 'ZZZZ'
   }
]

result = array1.map((o, i) => {
  return {...o, ...array2[i]};
});

console.log(result);
```